# Puzzles: Meander

Tags: grid-deduction

I have come up with an interesting type of puzzle based on the mathematical concept of a [meander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meander_(mathematics)). The concept, of course, is not original to me, but the type of puzzle is, as far as I know.

A meander is a curve that intersects a given line a certain number of times, but does not intersect itself. To complete each puzzle, you must draw a meander, starting at one red node and ending at another, that passes through all nodes on the given line. Additionally, each number above or below the line and between two of its nodes denotes the number of "arches" of the meander that must cover it, or segments of the meander on one side of the line that join two nodes on opposite sides of the number. Here is an example puzzle:

[image]

and here is a possible solution:

[image]

Here are 4 meander puzzles. Enjoy!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

If the rules of the puzzle are unclear, just let me know and I'll be happy to elaborate. Happy puzzling!

Comment: Do you have to alternate sides?

Comment: Yes, you do. The curve must *cross* the lines at the nodes, except for where it starts and ends.

Comment: Are solutions unique?

Comment: Nice! I like this idea

Comment: @Deusovi Hmm, not necessarily. I didn't check for uniqueness.

Comment: Then it's not grid deduction. The entire *point* of the genre is that solutions can be deduced from logic *alone*. ([Here's an alternate solution to 4, by the way.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62WZ7.png))

Comment: @Deusovi *Sigh.* Can you suggest a more appropriate tag to use?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Can't think of anything, really - this seems *very* grid-deduction-y, but the alternate solutions ruin it. (I *was* wondering why none of my deduction strategies were working, though.)

Comment: @Deusovi Bwahaha! No grid deduction strategies! >:D

Comment: ...That's a *bad* thing. It means you'll have to make a "guess" somewhere. (I [elaborated more](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38508858#38508858) on this in chat.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solutions:

Meander puzzle #1

> [image: meander 1]

Meander puzzle #2 (after update)

> [image: meander 2]

Meander puzzle #3

> [image: meander 3]

Meander puzzle #4

> [image: meander 4]

Comment: Nice! You're so close to getting all $4$...

Comment: @Nilknarf how do you draw the curves? i think i'm close to getting 2 and am not sure how to post the answer.

Comment: @Nilknarf Got all 4.  I didn't realize that #2 had been updated, I don't think it was solvable before.