# 4 More Meander Puzzles

Tags: grid-deduction

My [previous set of meander puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53063/puzzles-meander) was fairly well-received, so I decided to make some more.

If you didn't see the first set of meander puzzles, the instructions can be found [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53063/puzzles-meander).

Here they are:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Enjoy!

Comment: I don't think all of these have unique solutions (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZkXU.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/r17yx.png)

Comment: @ffao Well shoot. Thanks for tipping me off! :)

Comment: I *really* don't think this should be grid-deduction, maybe try pencil-and-paper games?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puzzle 1 solution

> [image: Jiggy-Spiral Squiggle]

Puzzle 2 solution

> [image: lopsided wormy-looking squiggle]

Puzzle 3 solution

> [image: vaguely moustache-looking squiggle]
>  The 0s and 1s made a pretty useful border, allowing it to be solved as basically three subsections

Puzzle 4 solution

> [image: Topographic Spiral squiggle]

Comment: Yep, these look good to me! Now, can you do the other two? :P